# Solace Dot Net Core SSL Issue

Tags: solace

I am trying to deploy a Solace app i have running on Dot Net Core on Windows to a linux x64 Ubuntu machine. Here is what I get when I try to run. Cant figure out how to fix this issues.

2018-08-23 19:38:39.374  SolaceConsumer :  LogEvent - Sdk     solClientDL.c:165                    (7fcc46ef1700) Could not load library 'libcrypto.so', error: libcrypto.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

2018-08-23 19:38:39.375  SolaceConsumer :  LogEvent - Sdk     solClient.c:12349                    (7fcc46ef1700) Failure in connecting session '(c0,s1)', reason 'solClientDL.c:165                    (7fcc46ef1700) Could not load library 'libcrypto.so', error: libcrypto.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'

Answer (score 1):

The issue is due to missing `libcrypto.so` and `libssl.so` libraries. Solace .NET and its underlying C API dynamically loads the SSL libraries when required.

At least on Ubunutu 18.04, there are two versions of OpenSSL libraries installed --- 1.0 and 1.1. Both of them are not named `libcrytpo.so` or `libssl.so`.

```
$ ldconfig -p | grep 'libssl\|libcrypto'
    libssl3.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl3.so
    libssl.so.1.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1
    libssl.so.1.0.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0
    libcrypto.so.1.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1
    libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
```

You need both `libcrypto.so` and `libssl.so` to point to the 1.0.0 version for the Solace API to work. This requires either:

1. Creating soft links to the respective OpenSSL 1.0 libraries, and have that path included in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, or
2. Install a package that does that for you.

For the latter, this can be done with:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libssl1.0-dev
```

Note that you cannot have both 1.1-dev and 1.0-dev:

```
$ apt-cache show libssl1.0-dev
Package: libssl1.0-dev
Architecture: amd64
...
Conflicts: libssl-dev
...
```